# How to extend the bullet content out further in Roam?

Tags: css

I've been trying for a while to get the bullets in Roam (`RoamResearch`) to extend all the way to where the filter button is in the "linked references" section at the bottom of the page. When the sidebar is close, the bullets actually do extend out that far and they can show more content on a single line. But I want to always have the bullets reach that far.

I've dug into the CSS but can't find out how. Here's a [link](https://roamresearch.com/#/app/help/page/80uPAx8m-) to the Roam help page with a demo graph to dig into.

I'll attach a screenshot below to show where I want it to extend. For some reason, I just can't figure this one out. I've used the developer tools in Chrome to try and figure it out, but I just can't.

[image]

Comment: You have a blank spacer div in there with the class `.rm-block-separator` that has a 114px `min-width` that is your culprit. However realistically I see a lot of stuff in there as far as DOM structure goes that shouldn't be done that way, and really flex shouldn't be needed for most of that page. You could get the same result with a fraction of the DOM elements and css that would still be more responsive. In the future though, it's best to provide a reproducible example instead of just pointing folks to an intrusive URL. Cheers.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks so much!